# ORA-00942: Table or View not exist connecting with another user

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

in Oracle SQL developer I got error `ORA-00942: Table or View not exist` connecting with another user when I do the following:

```
CREATE USER marta IDENTIFIED BY 'marta';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON myTable TO marta;
```

so then, executing:

```
CONNECT marta/marta;
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ('1', 'foo', bar');
```

got the ORA-00942...

Obviusly, If I use system user I can insert row with no issues.

I searched other answers but I couldnt solve this... what is wrong

Comment: In the second snippet, `insert into mytable ...` is short for `insert into marta.mytable ...`. Can you figure it out?

Comment: @Mat I have replaced to ```CONNECT marta/marta;
INSERT INTO marta.myTable VALUES ('1', 'foo', bar');``` but I got same error.

Comment: Well of course. Marta didn't create that table. `marta.myTable` doesn't exist.

Comment: Guess not. Try "INSERT INTO your_user_id.myTable VALUES ('1', 'foo', bar');"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Obviusly, If I use system user I can insert row with no issues.

Uh-oh. There's nothing obvious about that. The SYSTEM user should not own a table called MY_TABLE (or whatever application table that is actually named). The SYSTEM user is part of the Oracle database, its schema is governed by Oracle and using it for our own application objects is really bad practice.

But it seems you have created a table in that schema and user MARTA can't see it. That's standard. By default users can only see their own objects. They can only see objects in other schemas if the object's owner (or a power user) grants privileges on that object to the other user.

So, as SYSTEM

```
grant select on my_table to marta;
```

Then, as MARTA

```
select * from system.my_table;
```

To avoid prefixing the owning schema MARTA can create a synonym:

```
create or replace synonym my_table for system.my_table;

select * from my_table;
```

But really, you need to stop using SYSTEM for your own tables.

Comment: But really, you need to stop using SYSTEM for your own tables -> THIS